# AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x2012ebad8) & Versions/A/MobileDevice

Tags: ios, flutter, build, ipa, flutter-build

meilbeck new % flutter build ios
The plugins `flutter_geocoder, flutter_open_whatsapp` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if these plugins support the Android V2 embedding.
Otherwise, consider removing them since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding:
https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Building com.meilbeck for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 867JW4UJXC
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           19.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
objc[87290]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x2012ebad8) and
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1112542c8). One of the two will be used.
Which one is undefined.
objc[87290]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x2012ebb28) and
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x111254318). One of the two will be used.
Which one is undefined.
2022-03-18 15:18:58.509 xcodebuild[87290:648284]  DVTAssertions: Warning in
/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-19527/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:373
Details:  (null) deviceType from 7e6c53032d19882e548d8ba3e94aaa015c48cbcc was NULL when -platform called.
Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x125ebfcd0>
Method:   -platform
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x1140073b0>{number = 2, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2022-03-18 15:18:58.661 xcodebuild[87290:648293]  DVTAssertions: Warning in
/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-19527/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:373
Details:  (null) deviceType from 7e6c53032d19882e548d8ba3e94aaa015c48cbcc was NULL when -platform called.
Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x125ebfcd0>
Method:   -platform
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x120051510>{number = 6, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/0x/mj92vy8s15jf03g665gyt7g40000gn/T/flutter_tools.RtsbHM/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirUnd5CU/temporary_xcresult_bun
dle

```
Invalid depfile: /Users/pitcher/Desktop/mailbeck_new/meilbeck
new/.dart_tool/flutter_build/27c0044011412d1e1c8103768df5edea/kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: /Users/pitcher/Desktop/mailbeck_new/meilbeck
new/.dart_tool/flutter_build/27c0044011412d1e1c8103768df5edea/kernel_snapshot.d
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'firebase_core' in 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'firebase_messaging' in 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart'.
lib/main.dart:4:8: Error: Not found: 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart'
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart'
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:19:9: Error: Undefined name 'Firebase'.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
        ^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:89:28: Error: The getter 'FirebaseMessaging' isn't defined for the class '_MyHomePageState'.
 - '_MyHomePageState' is from 'package:meilbeck/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'FirebaseMessaging'.
    var firstToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_calendar_carousel-2.1.0/lib/flutter_calendar_carousel.dart:956:24:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart'
 ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
        WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                       ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_datetime_picker-1.5.1/lib/flutter_datetime_picker.dart:311:32:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'Color' which excludes null.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
                  color: theme.backgroundColor ?? Colors.white,
                               ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-3.2.0/lib/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provid
er.dart:109:29: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'PaintingBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'PaintingBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart'
 ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/binding.dart').
      () => PaintingBinding.instance?.imageCache?.evict(key),
                            ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-3.2.0/lib/src/image_provider/multi_image_stream_complete
r.dart:152:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart'
 ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
    SchedulerBinding.instance?.scheduleFrameCallback(_handleAppFrame);
                     ^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:package%3Afirebase_core%2Ffirebase_core.dart;
message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:653:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:793:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:614:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:1432:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:9:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
Failed to package /Users/pitcher/Desktop/mailbeck_new/meilbeck new.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order

Result bundle written to path:
    /var/folders/0x/mj92vy8s15jf03g665gyt7g40000gn/T/flutter_tools.RtsbHM/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirUnd5CU/temporary_xcresult_bun
    dle
```

Encountered error while building for device.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the following command from your flutter project root directory:

```
flutter pub add firebase_core
```

Kindly refer to [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#initialize-firebase) for more details.